# Avoiding subselect in the query with aggregate funcion

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT A.msisdn, A.times, sum(A.user_usage) as 'usage' 
FROM (SELECT S.msisdn, S.times, D.user_usage, 
             IF (S.times = 0, S.activation_date, S.last_attribution_date) as ref_date,  
             DATEDIFF(NOW(), IF (S.times = 0,  S.activation_date, S.last_attribution_date) ) as days, 
             D.transdate 
     from subs S 
     INNER JOIN daily_usage D ON (S.msisdn=D.msisdn) 
     where S.status=1) as A 
where A.days % 30 = 0 
    AND A.transdate between A.ref_date AND DATE(now()) 
    AND A.times <= 6 
group by A.msisdn, A.times;
```

I would like to know if there is way to avoid subselect in the above statement.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. At first I thought you unwrap the subselect and move the outer `WHERE` clause into its `HAVING` clause. But that will perform those tests **after** `SUM(user_usage)`, and your query requires that this be done **before** this aggregate.

Comment: Thank you very much anyway for your reply.